# Convolution with $\theta_t$(x) = $\frac{1}{t} \theta\bigl(\frac{x}{t}\bigr)$ for $\theta(x)$ with certain conditions

Tags: real-analysis, convolution

Let $\theta:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a measurable bounded function with bounded support such that $\int_\mathbb{R} \theta(x)dx = 1$ and $\theta\ge0$. Also let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a summable function.

Define $\theta_t$(x) = $\frac{1}{t} \theta\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)$

Show that $\lim\limits_{t\to0^+} ||f*\theta_t-f||_1 = 0$

I understand intuitively why it's true, but I didn't manage to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Young's Inequality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
|f\ast\theta_t(x)-f(x)|&=\Bigl|\int_\mathbb{R}\theta_t(y)(f(x-y)-f(x))\,dy\Bigr|\\
&\le\int_\mathbb{R}\theta_t(y)|f(x-y)-f(x)|\,dy\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\theta(y)|f(x-t\,y)-f(x)|\,dy.
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\int_\mathbb{R}|f\ast\theta_t(x)-f(x)|\,dx&\le\int_\mathbb{R}\int_\mathbb{R}\theta(y)|f(x-t\,y)-f(x)|\,dy\,dx\\
&=\int_\mathbb{R}\theta(y)\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x-t\,y)-f(x)|\,dx\,dy.
\end{align}$$
Now
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x-t\,y)-f(x)|\,dx\le2\,\|f\|_1
$$
and
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\int_\mathbb{R}|f(x-t\,y)-f(x)|\,dx=0\quad\forall y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
The dominated convergence theorem implies the result.

Comment: Great, Thank you !
How do you explain your last step?
I mean $\lim\limits_{t\to0}\int_R |f(x-ty)-f(x)|dx = 0?$

Comment: It is the continuity of the $L^1$ norm with respect to translation. Scheme of proof: 1) Show it for smooth functions (uniformly continuous is enough.) 2) Use a density argunment.